# What does "ingenuous" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives

> As well as the standard oratorio repertory, she sang solo recitals, her dazzling smile and enchantingly ingenuous personality creating an instant bond with audiences. <sup>[TELEGRAPH](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/music/opera/9019989/Kathleen-Ferrier-Consoling-angel-and-the-nations-darling.html)</sup>

I am a little bit confused about the definition of ingenuous on OALD:

> [ingenuous](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/ingenuous): honest, innocent and willing to trust people

What I am wondering about is *honest* in that definition. In my understanding it does not match with *innocent* and *willing to trust*.

Another definition on Oxford Dictionaries is less ambivalent:

> [ingenuous](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ingenuous): (of a person or action) innocent and unsuspecting:

But in the context above *honest* would make sense and, in any case, more than being naive. Moreover my favorite translation service provides some translation in meaning of being frankly so I suppose that *ingenuous* has two meanings: naivety and frankness.

What is the meaning of *ingenuous* in the given context and what is the precise definition in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an unusual adjective. In this case, it probably means "undisingenuous" — not attempting, or attempting to appear, to be something she isn't (so "honest" works for "ingenuous").

The "innocent and unsuspecting" is mirrored in the borrowed French noun [*ingénu(e)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingenue_%28stock_character%29) (innocent, virtuous, candid, lacking cunning...)

Comment: I also think it's an "unusual adjective". I was surprised to find that [according to NGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ingenuous%2Cdisingenuous&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), it's been appearing in print more often that *disengenuous* until the last couple of decades.

Comment: Does *undisingenuous* really exist?

Comment: Because of *undisingenuous* ... *disingenuous* isn't the antonym to *ingenuous*, is it?

Comment: @Em1, yes: if *ingenuous* means "honest, natural, real, sincere" and *disingenuous* means "dishonest, scheming, hiding something relevant", then they are antonyms. See also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61650/true-statements-with-hidden-meanings/). I coined *undisingenuous" to make it clear what I meant. At least, that's what I wanted to do!

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another from [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/ingenuous):

> 1 free from any intent to deceive or impress others
>   ex: *photographs that
>   capture the ingenuous smiles of young children at play*
>
> **Synonyms:** artless, **genuine**, honest, innocent, naive (or na{iuml}ve), **natural**, **real**, simple, **sincere**, true,
>   unaffected, unpretending, unpretentious

Solo voice recital requires more than singing.  I took voice for several years and was taught that premeditated physical expression (acting, basically) is equally important to proper projection and economy of breath in order to fully express a piece's narrative.

In the given context

> [2](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/music/opera/9019989/Kathleen-Ferrier-Consoling-angel-and-the-nations-darling.html) As well as the standard oratorio repertory, she sang solo recitals,
>   her dazzling smile and enchantingly ingenuous personality creating an
>   instant bond with audiences.

the synonyms I've made bold-face are those that speak to me with regard to what I was taught.

Answer (score 2):

The writer is using *ingenuous* in the sense of *ingenue*:

> **ingenue**, *noun* :
>   **1 a** : an ingenuous unsophisticated girl or young woman : a girl just entering society : DEBUTANTE {*suitable dress for an ingenue*};
>   **especially** : a stage part representing a character that is youthful, innocent, appealing, sweet, sympathetic {*musical comedy
>   ingenue*}

Note especially the last sense of Merriam-Webster's definition.