# Term for "to have a hidden purpose for being involved in something"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

The hidden purpose can be selfish or not. He or she is involved in something to ensure their purpose is fulfilled.

Example : She joined our group to help us. She has no _____.

He will only join us in this quest if he has ____.

Or am I asking too much and should settle for *hidden purpose* ?

Comment: "Ulterior motive"

Comment: @Ste That would have been my answer; perhaps you should make that an answer?  :)

Comment: I was on a teleconference when I commented with that answer as I didn't have time to write an answer.  Happy for @Rathony to take the points on that. :)

Comment: @Ste But Rathony has provided a different answer, which just happens to quote a definition that cites _another_ answer... a bit mind-boggling, but I'd vote for a standalone _ulterior motive_ since it was my 1st thought.

Comment: *a horse in this race*, *a vested interest* - but those are not necessarily hidden. Some of your sentences do not seem to apply to a (necessarily) **hidden** interest.

Comment: @Ste I guess I am lucky thanks to your teleconference. :-)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Consider using [hidden agenda](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hidden+agenda):

> An undisclosed plan, especially one with an **ulterior motive**.

[American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition]

As @Phil Sweet commented, you could also consider using "personal agenda" or just "agenda". I've just found a related question, [Meaning of “have an agenda”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24212/meaning-of-have-an-agenda).

Comment: Also *personal agenda*, which might be a tad less suspicious sounding in this context

Comment: I like how the definition quotes another candidate term, _ulterior motive_, which was the 1st one I thought of... making this sort of two answers in one, and the dictionary oddly self-referential.

Answer (score 32):

Consider [ulterior motive](https://www.google.com/search?q=ulterior+motive):

> If you say that someone has an ulterior motive for doing something, you believe that they have a hidden reason for doing it ⇒ Sheila had an ulterior motive for trying to help Stan.

Answer (score 3):

**Secret intention** or **hidden ploy**.

> This is what happens when a hidden ploy is unveiled; it can never work
>   the same way again, and can never have the same meaning or payoff for
>   the perpetrator (The New Way to Compete: How to Be a Winner in Your
>   Career and in Your Life, Harry A. Olson, [excerpt on G. Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=X_dNlM7HFVAC&lpg=PA92&ots=3DTPiOsgzD&dq=%22This%20is%20what%20happens%20when%20a%20hidden%20ploy%20is%20unveiled%3B%20it%20can%20never%20work%20the%20same%20way%20again%22&pg=PA92#v=onepage&q=%22This%20is%20what%20happens%20when%20a%20hidden%20ploy%20is%20unveiled;%20it%20can%20never%20work%20the%20same%20way%20again%22&f=false))

Answer (score 1):

**Angle at (something)** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/angle)

> *verb* To plan or scheme to get or achieve something; to try to get something in an indirect or roundabout way. (Usually used in the continuous tense.)
>
> *"We've been angling at securing a contract with a major development company from the Middle East for the last few months."*
> *"What exactly are you angling at? If it's a pay raise, you can just forget about it."*

**Angle** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/angle)

> *noun* 2. a scheme or deception; a pivotal or critical feature of a scheme; the gimmick in a scheme or plot.
>
> *"I got a new angle to use in a con job on the old guy."*

Comment: The use of *angle*, in your first sense, is essentially unknown in the US, except in a few idioms.  And in any context where you attempted to use the second, most people would interpret the word to mean "direction".  In fact "a new angle" is an idiom meaning "an new direction", and no deceit is implied.

Comment: @HotLicks I see. But I have heard it a lot.. in movies and TV series, especially those crime and CSI kind. :)

Comment: And when you hear it, the meaning is "an new approach" or "a new direction", or perhaps "a new piece of information".  "Frank, I have a new angle on the Smith case."

Comment: @HotLicks Not at all. See the link I have cited. You are talking about sense 1. I have quoted sense 2 and only sense 2. (McGraw-Hill')

Comment: I for one heard it so much as a non-native speaker that I would have added it as my own answer if it had not been already.

Comment: Your quote above for sense two is basically using "a new approach".  I could just as easily say "I have a new angle on how to fix that LSJD bug in the KLKH application."

Comment: @HotLicks Please go to [this link.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/angle) and scroll to the end. See McGraw Hill section. I quoted sense 2. You're discussing sense 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Hidden agenda**
Is the phrase I would use in this context, but I think it has negative connotations, so I wouldn't use it in a positive or neutral setting.

Answer (score 0):

I searched Google for Definition of Agenda.
Here is their third case:
the underlying intentions or motives of a particular person or group.
"Miller has his own agenda and it has nothing to do with football"

Comment: Intentions being "underlying" doesn't mean they're hidden.
*hidden* agenda, OTOH...

Answer (score 0):

Along with the answers already provided, I believe **insidious** fits the bill for your definition:

> **insidious**: stealthily treacherous or deceitful; operating or proceeding in an inconspicuous or seemingly harmless way but actually with grave effect.

Answer (score 0):

**Malintent**

I cant seem to find standard references, maybe because this is a relatively new word. But anyway, looks like this is the only single word answer.

Ref: [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malintent), [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=malintent)

Edit: Sorry, did not see the 'insidious' entry.

Answer (score -1):

Expedient

> [expedient](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expedient)
>   /ɪkˈspiːdɪənt,ɛkˈspiːdɪənt/
>
> adjective
>   (of an action) convenient and practical although possibly
>   improper or immoral.
>
> noun
>   a means of attaining an end, especially one that is convenient
>   but possibly improper or immoral.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. "Expedient" as a noun does not seem to fit the question.I would put some more thought to this.

Comment: If you quote someone else's words, it's essential that you make this clear (eg using quotation marks or blockquote formatting) and acknowledge the source. It's not only polite to give the original author credit, it also avoids the more serious charge of *plagiarism*. I've edited your post accordingly, but please include correct attribution in future :-)